# connecting to a database through JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to follow a tutorial in a book on connecting a program to a database with JDBC. I am confused on what the first block of code is doing in the class. whan i run the code i get an error saying that `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/book_store`

and the code is throwing an exception in that first block inside the class. do i need to add some sort of dependency or library to the project?

as you can tell this is my first attempt at using a db...

```
package com.apress.books.dao;

import com.apress.books.model.Author;
import com.apress.books.model.Book;
import com.apress.books.model.Category;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookDAOImpl implements BookDAO {

static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    }
}

private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/book_store",
            "root", "password");
}

private void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
    if (connection == null)
        return; try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
}
@Override
public void insert(Book book) {

}

@Override
public void update(Book book) {

}

@Override
public void delete(Long bookId) {

}
}
```

Comment: You need the mysql driver jar in  your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence this is a ClassNotFoundException. Your first catch clause is empty and thus, although the exception is being caught, you are not acting upon it. In the least, I would do something like this:

```
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This would help you to see better what is causing your troubles.

Moving on to a solution:

If you are using Maven, you need to add the following dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.35</version>
</dependency>
```

And if you want, change the version to any one found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

Otherwise, you need to download the jar from the same link and include it in your project dependencies.